# How to extract lines from text file "block" in loop

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep, text-files

I have a huge text file and I want to use grep to search if some "blocks" in my text file is existing in another file. So, I need to extract these blocks first.

This is my file:

```
>gi|60117238|gb|AY897435.1| Wolbachia endosymbiont of Drosophila mojavensis, genomic survey sequence
TCTGTTGCGAGTGTGCTGATAACTACTGAATCTATGATAGTTGATGTACCAAGCAAAGAAAATGCTTCATCTCCTATGGG
TGCAGGAGAAATGAGTGGCATGGGTGGATTCTAAGTAGAATGAAACCGTGGAGCAATTGCTCCACGGTAGTTCCAAAAAA
TCTCACATTTTACTATTCGTTAAAGGTAATACGTTTGGTGCAGAAATGCACTACTGTTTGCATCCGTTTCGCTCCTTTAT
ATTGTGGTTGTCTAATAACAAAAAGGCAGCATAAGAAAACTATAACACCTAGTATATTTATACTATAGCTGACCCAAGCA
ACACGTCATACCGCGATTCATTCCACAACTGTACGAACATTACAATATGGCACATAGTAAACGATGTCATGAAAGTAGCT
GACACTGGAATTCAGAAAAAAGGATTATGTCATTCCAGTGCTTGACACTGGAATCCAGCATTTCCATAATCATCAAAACA
TTGTATTTTAACAAAAAACATGTATTTTTATGCTTGCCAACTTAATAAAATTCCTGGATCCCAGTGTCAAGCACTGGGAT
GACAC
>gi|60117239|gb|AY897436.1| Wolbachia endosymbiont of Drosophila mojavensis, genomic survey sequence
TTTTCATCGCTCATGTCCTTAGTTTACCCCCTGTTTCACCATTACATTAATATCTACAGAACCTCCCACTGGGGAGTAGT
AATCTAGGATAGTTTCTATCACTAAAACGCGTGGTATTCCTTTATTTTTTACCAATTTTAAATAAGACAATACCTTATTA
TCATCATAATGCTGCAGAAAGCGGCAAAAGACACCTAATTCATAATTTGTAGCTGATAATTCTTCTTGAGTTATGAGTTT
AATTTTTAAATCTTCTACTGCCTGCCTAGGCACTTTATGTTCGTTGTAATAATATAAGCCTATAGAACCTTTATTGTGTA
TATCAGAATAAGCAAGAAATAAAGAGTGTACGCCAAATAGCAATATATTTTTAGCACCATCTATATTAACCCTAGAATTA
AACTCTTTAGTGTCAAACCTGGAATATCCTAGCAATGCTTGGTAAAACGCTATTTTCCTGTCTTCTGATGTTTCTTTCTC
CTTAAAAAGAATCAAATGAAAATATTGACTCCTGCCTTAAAATATCCGGCATTTTTAACCAATTCTTTTCAGCGGCAACC
CTTGCCCACATTGCTGCTGCTTTAGGAAAAATGGTATTTCTTTAAACACTTACCTTTTGATGAAAGTTGCCCAAAATCCT
TTGTTCTATCCGAATCCAAAACCCCTATTTCCCAAACGCCCCTTAAAACCTTTTTTAAAATTGGAACAAAAAATATTTAA
TTTTTAAAAAAAAACG
>gi|60117240|gb|AY897437.1| Wolbachia endosymbiont of Drosophila mojavensis, genomic survey sequence
TTGNCCATCAATTGGCCACCAGAAAAGTTGCGTCCGTTTACTTCTACACCATGTATAAATGCACCTAAAATCATGCCTTG
GCAAAATGCAGCACCAAGTGACCCAAAATGAAAGGCATAATCCCATAATCGCCTGTATTTTCCTTCTGCCTTAAAACGAA
ACTCAAAGGATACTCCGCGCACTATAAGGCCAAGCAGCATAATAATGATTGGAATATAAAAAGCAGGCATTAATATTGAA
TATGCAAGAGGAAAAGCAGCAAACAACCCTCCACCACCTAGTACCAACCATGTTTCGTTTCCATCCCAAAATGGTGCAAT
TGAGCTTATCATGTGATCACGGCATTTATCTGACGGTGCAAAAGGAAGTAAAATACCAATACCTAAATCAAACCCATCCA
TTAAAATATACAGTAAAACAGCTATGGCAATTAGTAATCCCCAGATTAGGGGTAAATTAATTAAGGAAGAAAAATCAAAC
ATGATTGTTGTCCTTTCCAGATGTACCAGCATCAATCACTGAAGCTCCAATACCGTGTTTATAAAATTGCTCTTCTTCTT
TAATGACAGGAATTCCTTTGTATATAAGTTTCAGAATATAGTATCTACCTGCTCCAAATATAAGGGTATACATAAACGAT
AAATGCAATCAAAGACCATGCAACCTGAGGACCGGTAATCGCAGATGAAAATGATTCAATTGTGCCGTTAATTCCATATA
CAGTGTAAAGTTGACGGCCAATTTCATAGTAAACCAAACTGCAAGTAACGCTATGGACCCCGACGGCATCTTTGAAATCC
ACAATCCTTTGAAAACACAACTTTGGAATAATTTGCCCCGAAAAATACTGAAAAAAAATTTACTGGACCCATTTTGGATT
ATTAAAATTTCAACTCCAACCATTTATACGGG
```

Block is starting from > to the letter befor the next >.

So, 1st block is:

```
TCTGTTGCGAGTGTGCTGATAACTACTGAATCTATGATAGTTGATGTACCAAGCAAAGAAAATGCTTCATCTCCTATGGG
TGCAGGAGAAATGAGTGGCATGGGTGGATTCTAAGTAGAATGAAACCGTGGAGCAATTGCTCCACGGTAGTTCCAAAAAA
TCTCACATTTTACTATTCGTTAAAGGTAATACGTTTGGTGCAGAAATGCACTACTGTTTGCATCCGTTTCGCTCCTTTAT
ATTGTGGTTGTCTAATAACAAAAAGGCAGCATAAGAAAACTATAACACCTAGTATATTTATACTATAGCTGACCCAAGCA
ACACGTCATACCGCGATTCATTCCACAACTGTACGAACATTACAATATGGCACATAGTAAACGATGTCATGAAAGTAGCT
GACACTGGAATTCAGAAAAAAGGATTATGTCATTCCAGTGCTTGACACTGGAATCCAGCATTTCCATAATCATCAAAACA
TTGTATTTTAACAAAAAACATGTATTTTTATGCTTGCCAACTTAATAAAATTCCTGGATCCCAGTGTCAAGCACTGGGAT
GACAC
```

2nd block is:

```
TTTTCATCGCTCATGTCCTTAGTTTACCCCCTGTTTCACCATTACATTAATATCTACAGAACCTCCCACTGGGGAGTAGT
AATCTAGGATAGTTTCTATCACTAAAACGCGTGGTATTCCTTTATTTTTTACCAATTTTAAATAAGACAATACCTTATTA
TCATCATAATGCTGCAGAAAGCGGCAAAAGACACCTAATTCATAATTTGTAGCTGATAATTCTTCTTGAGTTATGAGTTT
AATTTTTAAATCTTCTACTGCCTGCCTAGGCACTTTATGTTCGTTGTAATAATATAAGCCTATAGAACCTTTATTGTGTA
TATCAGAATAAGCAAGAAATAAAGAGTGTACGCCAAATAGCAATATATTTTTAGCACCATCTATATTAACCCTAGAATTA
AACTCTTTAGTGTCAAACCTGGAATATCCTAGCAATGCTTGGTAAAACGCTATTTTCCTGTCTTCTGATGTTTCTTTCTC
CTTAAAAAGAATCAAATGAAAATATTGACTCCTGCCTTAAAATATCCGGCATTTTTAACCAATTCTTTTCAGCGGCAACC
CTTGCCCACATTGCTGCTGCTTTAGGAAAAATGGTATTTCTTTAAACACTTACCTTTTGATGAAAGTTGCCCAAAATCCT
TTGTTCTATCCGAATCCAAAACCCCTATTTCCCAAACGCCCCTTAAAACCTTTTTTAAAATTGGAACAAAAAATATTTAA
TTTTTAAAAAAAAACG
```

Third block:

```
TTGNCCATCAATTGGCCACCAGAAAAGTTGCGTCCGTTTACTTCTACACCATGTATAAATGCACCTAAAATCATGCCTTG
GCAAAATGCAGCACCAAGTGACCCAAAATGAAAGGCATAATCCCATAATCGCCTGTATTTTCCTTCTGCCTTAAAACGAA
ACTCAAAGGATACTCCGCGCACTATAAGGCCAAGCAGCATAATAATGATTGGAATATAAAAAGCAGGCATTAATATTGAA
TATGCAAGAGGAAAAGCAGCAAACAACCCTCCACCACCTAGTACCAACCATGTTTCGTTTCCATCCCAAAATGGTGCAAT
TGAGCTTATCATGTGATCACGGCATTTATCTGACGGTGCAAAAGGAAGTAAAATACCAATACCTAAATCAAACCCATCCA
TTAAAATATACAGTAAAACAGCTATGGCAATTAGTAATCCCCAGATTAGGGGTAAATTAATTAAGGAAGAAAAATCAAAC
ATGATTGTTGTCCTTTCCAGATGTACCAGCATCAATCACTGAAGCTCCAATACCGTGTTTATAAAATTGCTCTTCTTCTT
TAATGACAGGAATTCCTTTGTATATAAGTTTCAGAATATAGTATCTACCTGCTCCAAATATAAGGGTATACATAAACGAT
AAATGCAATCAAAGACCATGCAACCTGAGGACCGGTAATCGCAGATGAAAATGATTCAATTGTGCCGTTAATTCCATATA
CAGTGTAAAGTTGACGGCCAATTTCATAGTAAACCAAACTGCAAGTAACGCTATGGACCCCGACGGCATCTTTGAAATCC
ACAATCCTTTGAAAACACAACTTTGGAATAATTTGCCCCGAAAAATACTGAAAAAAAATTTACTGGACCCATTTTGGATT
ATTAAAATTTCAACTCCAACCATTTATACGGG
```

How can I loop my file and extract one block in each iteration? To grep it with the other file?

Edit 1:

For more clarification:

I want to do some operation on each block. First, I perform diff between two files and but the result in a new file. For the new file which contains the blocks, i want to search if each block is included in the first file or in the second file. If it is included in the first file, i want to extract it to another new file. If it is included in the second file, i want to escape and go to next block.

Hope you getting my point.

Thanks,

Comment: Don't see no > in the 'file', typo?

Comment: @POW It is before every occurrence of (gi)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create a separate file for each block? And then you want to do any operation on those files? Or you just want to do some operation(say search/grep) for each block in each loop iteration? Please clarify your requirement.

Comment: I want to do some operation on each block. First, I perform diff between two files and but the result in a new file. For the new file which contains the blocks, i want to search if each block is included in the first file or in the second file. If it is included in the first file, i want to extract it to another new file. If it is included in the second file, i want to escape and go to next block.

Comment: I didn't get u clearly. All I got from ur end is as below:
You have a text file containing huge amount of textual data which contains some special character(>gi) based on which you are identifying the text blocks. You have one other file in which you want to search for the block (obtained from first file after separating using the special character set (>gi) and finally, you want to extract the blocks matched in second file to another file and leave the blocks that are not found in the second file in the first file as it is.